# Close a program if a key is being pressed when opening it in osx

Tags: c++, macos

I'm trying to make a program that closes itself -or only runs the line of code that closes it- whenever a certain key is in the pressed state when the program is run, so, if I start the program and the 'c' key is pressed, the program must stop.

Note that `cin` or `read` doesn't help here, because it waits until you press enter to detect a keystroke. In a way, I'm looking for a way to detect the async key state(because the cursor may not be focused in the program's console window) in osx using c++.

Comment: There are libraries like [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) that can capture keystroke events and let you bind functions to them, which in this case could be closing the program.

Comment: @CoryKramer I'm looking for vanilla c++ if possible, without libraries.